# c++ receive packets from broadcast station

Tags: c++, networking

I'm programming a c++ client to receive packets from a server (UDP broadcast). This is a hardware switch (One direction only) system so I have no information regarding the senders address or any other info. It all compiles and binds OK but no packets received.

```
WSAStartup(0x0101, &_wsaData);
memset((char *)&_sockaddr, 0, sizeof(_sockaddr));
_sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr   = _nAdapterIp;
_sockaddr.sin_family        = _nadressFam;
_sockaddr.sin_port      = _usPort; //Gave it a try with (0) - also not working
_socket = socket(_nadressFam, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); //Gave it a try with (17) - UDP for the 3 rd parameter - not working
char broadcast='1';
setsockopt(_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast ,sizeof(broadcast));
bind(_socket, (sockaddr*) & _sockaddr, sizeof (_sockaddr));
char* recvbuf = new char[_nPacketSize + 1];
int nSize = recv(_socket, recvbuf, _nPacketSize + 1, 0);
```

Comment: Should `_usPort` be `htons(_usPort)` or is it already network-order?

Comment: You should generally test function return code and handle errors (call to `socket`, `setsockopt`, `bind`, etc...

Comment: @jbh has a great point too. Any of those calls could have failed and you wouldn't even know. Networking code should be _bullet-proof_.

Comment: Thanks, it's not there (i shorten it) all tests show that bind and setsockopt working fine.....

Answer (score 1):

Answer a bit long for a comment even if I am not sure it's the only caveat in your snippet

Your call to `setsockopt` is valid, but your fourth argument is not good as you are passing the **character** 1 which is in fact the decimal value 49.

```
unsigned char broadcast = 1;
if (setsockopt(_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast ,sizeof(broadcast)) == -1) {
  //handle errors appropriately
}
```

Comment: char broadcast= (char)1; if (setsockopt(_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast ,sizeof(broadcast)) != 0) { fprintf(stderr, "Could not set socket options.\n"); WSACleanup(); exit(0); } But it stiil get's no packets.....

Comment: Well, to be able to answer completely, we will need the entire original code which treat udp socket. It is also possible that you do not listen on the correct port. Give us a little more detail on what you are trying to achieve.